# Reusing form in JSF with different methods in input values

Tags: jsf

I learn JSF 2.3. I have two pages with very similar form, one to create an item, another one to edit it. I would like to use one file for it (form.xhtml) not to repeat myself, so there is my create-form.xhtml here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"    
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    
<h:form id="add-form" prependId="false">
 
        <div ><h4>#{requestTools.createFormLabels()[0]}</h4></div>
        <p class="form-group">
            <h:inputTextarea id="todo-text" 
                             class="form-control" 
                             title="#{msg.todoText}" 
                             rows="3" 
                             p:placeholder="#{msg.todoText}" 
                             
                             value="#{newTodoItem.text}"                            
                             
                             required="true" 
                             requiredMessage="#{msg.messageTodoText}">
            </h:inputTextarea>
        </p>
        <p class="form-group">
            <h:outputLabel for="datetime" value="#{msg.deadlineLabel}"/>
            <input type="datetime-local" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   name="datetime" 
                   id="datetime"
                   jsf:id="datetime" 
                   
                   jsf:value="#{newTodoItem.userInputDate}"
                   
                   required="true" 
                   requiredMessage="#{msg.messageDeadline}">                        
                <f:convertDateTime for="datetime" timeStyle="full" 
                                   pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
                                   type="both"/>
            </input>
        </p>   
        <p class="form-group">
            <h:outputLabel for="author" value="#{msg.authorLabel}"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu class="author"
                              id="author"
                              
                              value ="#{newTodoItem.author}"
                              
                              required="true" requiredMessage="Author is required">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Ivo" itemLabel="Ivo"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Olinka" itemLabel="Olinka"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </p>
        <hr/>
        <p class="form-group">
            <h:commandButton class="btn btn-sm btn-light" 
                            value = "#{requestTools.createFormLabels()[1]}" 
                            action = "#{todoItemBean.createNewTask(newTodoItem)}"/>
        </p>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

The `edit-form.xhtml` should be almost the same. The difference is that input values should be for example `#{todoItemBean.newItem.text}` instead of `#{newTodoItem.text}`.
I tried some `<c:if test="#{requestTools.getSegment(3) eq 'edit.xhtml'}">`... conditions (`requestTools#getSegments(i)` returns the i-th segment of uri) but this didn't work, since the difference is inside `<input>` tag. To use `<c:if ...` tag before `<input>` tag wouldn't make much help, it wouldn't simplify the code, since repeating the code would be necessary.
Are composite components a way to deal with it? Or, is there any easier solution? Can you please help me with it? I appologize if my question is stupid, but after a few days googling and searching here on stackoverflow or in books I didn't find solution which suits my problem.

Comment: You'd probably either create tag files or (as you already mentioned) composite components (cc). But I'd suggest to place the cc inside forms, not forms inside cc. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Comment: @Selaron Thank you for your hint, I'm guessing cc are a bit complicated to use for just two forms, so I'll look at tag files, it didn't come to my mind before.